# Getting View Object from within a Zend Controller plugin

Tags: zend-framework, plugins, zend-view, front-controller

In my controller, I have a postDispatch to consolidate my FlashMessenger messages:

```
public function postDispatch()
{       
    $messages = $this->_helper->getHelper ( 'FlashMessenger' )
        ->getMessages ();

    if ( $this->_helper->getHelper ( 'FlashMessenger' )
        ->hasCurrentMessages () )
    {
        $messages = array_merge ( $messages, $this->_helper->getHelper ( 'FlashMessenger' )
            ->getCurrentMessages () );
        $this->_helper->getHelper ( 'FlashMessenger' )
            ->clearCurrentMessages ();
    }

    $this->view->alert = $messages;
}
```

I want to make this into a Controller plugin.

UPDATE: I realized why I need this - I want to pass my flash messages in JSON when called by the JSON context. Unless the messages are added to the View object, I don't receive the messages.

I was able to get the messages into an array, but I don't know how to pass them to the view:

```
class Plugin_FlashMessenger extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function postDispatch($request)
    {
        $flashmessenger = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper ( 'FlashMessenger' );

        $messages = $flashmessenger->getMessages ();
        if ( $flashmessenger->hasCurrentMessages () )
        {
            $messages = array_merge ( $messages, $flashmessenger->getCurrentMessages () );
            $flashmessenger->clearCurrentMessages ();
        }

        // THIS LINE IS WRONG. HOW DO I SEND $messages TO THE VIEW?
        $this->view->alert = $messages;
    }
}
```

Bonus question - is this the right way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I found your post while searching for the same thing.  Based on [this thread](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Get-View-object-inside-a-controller-plugin-td1744981.html), there are two simple ways to accomplish it.

**One:** If your view is initialized during bootstrap (`resources.view[] =` is in your `application.ini`), you can simply call this:

```
$view = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
        ->getParam('bootstrap')
        ->getResource('view');
```

**Two:** If your view is not initialized during bootstrap:

```
$viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
if (null === $viewRenderer->view) {
    $viewRenderer->initView();
}
$view = $viewRenderer->view;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's the wrong way to do it. The FlashMessenger is to have little notifications from one request to the next; available in the **view**.

Thus, the flashmessenger is already a controller action helper (for the above purpose) why do you want to build another helper on top of that? :)

So, your problem is actually getting the messages in the view. For that, there is already a view helper. From [noumenal](http://blog.noumenal.co.uk/2009/08/using-zend-framework-flashmessenger.html). It's awesome.

Comment: The FlashMessenger renders alerts on the next page. So if you want to send pages to *this* page, you need to do some logic (get previous messages, get current messages, combine them). So I should just put the logic in my layout/view? That's certainly much simpler, but I thought it was bad practice to have logic like that in the view scripts?

Comment: @Corey, the Noumenal Flash Messenger View Helper mentioned already handles the getMessages()/getCurrentMessages() logic for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to get this functionality in all of your controllers, you can just extend the Zend_Controller_Action and make a new class containing your post dispatch code.

Comment: Thanks. Getting the functionality into all controllers is exactly what I want. I'd created my own library, but it seems clunky. I'd rather add/remove a plugin and get the functionality.