# Getting access to Zend_Controller_Action::$view from Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract::postDispatch()

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm looking at refactoring some code out of an Actions postDispatch into a plugin. The code currently is assigning a value to the view object and I can't find out how to get access to the view object from inside the plugin.

The old Zend_Controller_Action::postDispatch():

```
public function postDispatch() {
  ...
  $this->view->flashMessages = array_merge($flashMessenger->getCurrentMessages(), $flashMessenger->getMessages());
  ...
}
```

The new Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract::postDispatch():

```
public function postDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
  ...
  // How to get access to Zend_Controller_Action::$view?
  // $this->view->flashMessages = array_merge($flashMessenger->getCurrentMessages(), $flashMessenger->getMessages());
  ...
}
```

Is there a straight forward way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907490/getting-view-object-from-within-a-zend-controller-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$view = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap')->getResource('view');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function postDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{
    $flashMessages = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('FlashMessenger')->getMessages();

    $view = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView();
    $view->flashMessages = $flashMessages->getCurrentMessages();
}
```